# Android utilizando webservice NetBeans

Tags: android, web-service

Gostaria de algumas informações, exemplos ou tutorias como deve pesquisar e oque estudar para ser que eu possa desenvolver esse projeto. Tenho pronto ja banco de dados e alguns componentes do web service gostaria de saber como implementá-lo no android.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o [KSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ksoap2/files/ksoap2/2.1.2/).

O acesso é simples:

```
// Criar o objeto SOAP
SoapObject soap = new SoapObject(namespace, metodo);
//Setar parametros
soap.addPropoerty(nome, valor);
//Envelopar Requisição
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soap);
```

Depois basta chamar o serviço:

```
HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
httpTransport.call("", envelope);
```

retirei tudo isso deste tutorial [aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/consumindo-webservices-em-aplicacoes-android/26866). Sugiro que o leio em caso de dúvidas.

Comment: O mais facil e melhor para utilizar é o KSOAP? vi algo sobre o Gson e alguns outros saberia qual mais facil e qual melhor para utilizar, tenho serias dificuldades nessa parte de comunicação

Comment: Facilidade é relativa. Depende do seu grau de conhecimento na lib.